# How to set up signingConfigs only for release variants?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, release

I've set up continuous deployment with fastlane that handles my code signing for release apps, annoying bit is that when I run them in debug in on my machine android studio fails because it can't find path to them (they are declared as env variables demonstrated below). I can fix this by creating dummy data for the env variables, but would rather android studio ignore this bit of code unless it is running a release buid.

So in my `app/build.gradle` right after `defaultConfig` I have

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file(System.getenv("MYAPP_STOREFILE"))
        storePassword System.getenv("MYAPP_STORE_PASSWORD")
        keyAlias System.getenv("MYAPP_KEY_ALIAS")
        keyPassword System.getenv("MYAPP_KEY_PASSWORD")
    }
}
```

I thought that putting it under `release` would do the trick, but no luck :/

Comment: Wrap it in an `if` block, so that code is skipped if the environment variables are not there.

Comment: @CommonsWare whole `signingConfigs` or something similar to what dipdipdip suggested?

Comment: If there is nothing else in `signingConfigs` that you need, wrap all of `signingConfigs`. I don't use environment variables with Gradle, so I'm not 100% certain what `getenv()` does if the variable is not there. If it throws an exception, use the `try`/`catch` block suggested by dipdipdip. If it just returns `null` or an empty string or something, `if` should work. [I use that approach for values pulled from `gradle.properties`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-document/blob/v0.2.0/document/build.gradle#L27-L80), for example, skipping portions of Gradle config if the property is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a super elegant solution, but just wrap it with try-catch?

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        try {
            storeFile file(System.getenv("MYAPP_STOREFILE"))
            storePassword System.getenv("MYAPP_STORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("MYAPP_KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("MYAPP_KEY_PASSWORD")
       } catch (Exception ignored) {
            // Do stuff or just ignore
       }
    }
}
```

If you don't want try-catch you can try the following:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile System.getenv("MYAPP_STOREFILE") ? file(System.getenv("MYAPP_STOREFILE")) : null
        storePassword System.getenv("MYAPP_STORE_PASSWORD")
        keyAlias System.getenv("MYAPP_KEY_ALIAS")
        keyPassword System.getenv("MYAPP_KEY_PASSWORD")
    }
}
```

Comment: try / catch works, could you please demonstrate example that prints exception to console as a warning as a sort of reminder please? I'm using react-native, android is not my strongest side. I can just print line, but if I can highlight it as warning, that would be better.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can show a warning in the "Messages" View. However you could either print the Stacktrace or log a warning via `logger.warn("your message")`. But I guess every developer will miss it.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin DSL you can use the below signing config:

```kotlin
signingConfigs {
  create("release") {
    storeFile = System.getenv("KEY_STORE_FILE")?.let { file(it) }
    storePassword = System.getenv("KEY_STORE_PASSWORD")
    keyAlias = System.getenv("KEY_ALIAS")
    keyPassword = System.getenv("KEY_PASSWORD")
  }
}
```

This configuration allows you to sync, build and run your project for the build variant `debug` without defining any of the values (reducing the setup steps for new developers) and succeeds on signed release builds only when the environment variables are defined.

Very useful when only specific developers have access to the key store file.